# Stalks of exterior power

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, multilinear-algebra

Assume we have a ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathscr{F}$. Then I want to see that for all $x\in X$ we have an isomorphism $$(\bigwedge_{\mathcal{O}_X}^r\mathscr{F})_x\stackrel{\simeq}{\longrightarrow}\bigwedge^r_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}\mathscr{F}_x$$ of $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-modules, and I read in Goertz/Wedhorn that this follows from the fact that exterior-powers commute with direct limits for abstract modules over a ring. With this in mind, I started the computation with \begin{align*}
(\bigwedge_{\mathcal{O}_X}^r\mathscr{F})_x&\cong (\bigwedge^r_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathscr{F})^{\operatorname{pre}}_x\\
&\cong \varinjlim_{x\in U}\bigwedge^r_{\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)}\Gamma(U,\mathscr{F})\\
&\cong \bigwedge^r_{\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)}\varinjlim_{x\in U}\Gamma(U,\mathscr{F}),
\end{align*} but then I got stuck because although I could go over to $\mathscr{F}_x$ in the argument of the latter exterior power, I wouldn't get rid of the $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{O}_X)$ in the index, and so I am a bit confused how to finish this off so that we get an isomorphism with respect to the $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you cite from Gortz and Wedhorn is that exterior powers commute with filtered inductive limits of modules over a fixed base ring - this requires more work to apply to your situation because your base rings are changing. Though this can be done, I prefer a different approach: let us prove that exterior powers commute with pullback for morphisms of ringed spaces, which will solve the problem after being applied to the morphism $(\{x\},\mathcal{O}_{X,x})\to (X,\mathcal{O}_X)$.

Let $f:Y\to X$ be a morphism of ringed spaces, let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, let $T^n(\mathcal{F})=\mathcal{F}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\cdots\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{F}$ be the $n$-fold tensor product, and let $\mathcal{K}_n(\mathcal{F})$ be the subsheaf of $T^n(\mathcal{F})$ generated by tensors with two entries equal. Then we have an exact sequence $$0\to \mathcal{K}\to T^n(\mathcal{F})\to \bigwedge^n\mathcal{F}\to 0,$$ and we can pull it back along $f$ to get a right-exact sequence $$ f^*\mathcal{K}\to f^*T^n(\mathcal{F})\to f^*\bigwedge^n\mathcal{F}\to 0.$$
As [tensor products commute with arbitrary pullbacks of ringed spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/92421/), we have that $f^*T^n(\mathcal{F})=T^n(f^*\mathcal{F})$. If we can show that $f^*\mathcal{K}$ surjects on to the subsheaf of $T^n(f^*\mathcal{F})$ generated by tensors with two entries equal, we win: this gives that $f^*\bigwedge^n\mathcal{F}=\bigwedge^nf^*\mathcal{F}$ because they're the same quotient.

But this is rather straightforward: by expanding a local section of $T^n(f^*\mathcal{F})$ with two coordinates equal in to a sum of pure tensors, it suffices to treat the case of $t=x\otimes x\otimes \cdots$ where $x=\sum a_i\otimes g_i$ for $a_i$ a local section of $f^{-1}\mathcal{F}$ and $g_i$ a local section of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ and all the entries in $\cdots$ are local sections of $f^{-1}\mathcal{F}$. Then $t= \sum_{i,j} (a_i\otimes g_i)\otimes (a_j\otimes g_j)\otimes \cdots$, and we see that $g_i^2(a_i\otimes a_i\otimes \cdots)$ and $g_ig_j(a_i\otimes a_j\otimes \cdots+a_j\otimes a_i\otimes \cdots)$ are all in the image of $f^*\mathcal{K}\to T^n(f^*\mathcal{F})$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is it possible that $a_i$ should be a local section of $f^{-1}\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Sure, that's fine too. I guess I was choosing a representative in the limit, but your suggestion is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "I am a bit confused how to finish this off so that we get an isomorphism with respect to the OX,x-module structure."

**Answer:** If $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is a scheme and $\mathcal{E}$ a finite rank locally trivial sheaf on $\mathcal{E}$, let $f:Y \rightarrow X$ be a map of schemes. Tensor operations such as exterior products and symmetric products commute with pullback:

$$f^*Sym^d(\mathcal{E}) \cong Sym^d(f^*\mathcal{E})\text{ and}f^*(\wedge^r \mathcal{E}) \cong \wedge^r(f^*(\mathcal{E})).$$

Let $x\in U:=Spec(A) \subseteq X$ be an open affine set containing $x$ with $\mathcal{E}(U):=E$.
If $j: Spec(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) \rightarrow U$ and $i:U \rightarrow X$ are the canonical map, it follows

$$i^*(\wedge^r \mathcal{E})\cong \wedge^r (\mathcal{E}_U)  $$

and

$$(\wedge^r \mathcal{E})_x:=( i \circ j)^*(\wedge^r(\mathcal{E}))=j^*(\wedge^r \mathcal{E}_U)=\wedge^r(j^*(\mathcal{E}_U))=\wedge^r(E_{\mathfrak{p}}) \cong \wedge^r(\mathcal{E}_x)$$

where $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq A$ is the prime ideal corresponding to $x$.

You must convince yourself that

$$B\otimes_A Sym^d_A(E) \cong Sym_B^d(B\otimes_A E)\text{ and }B\otimes_A \wedge^r_A E \cong \wedge_B^r(B\otimes_A E).$$

Hence if $B:=A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and $\phi: A \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is the canonical map you get

$$Sym^d_A(E)_{\mathfrak{p}} \cong A_{\mathfrak{p}}\otimes_A Sym^d_A(E) \cong 
Sym^d_{A_{\mathfrak{p}}}(A_{\mathfrak{p}}\otimes_A E) \cong$$

$$Sym^d_{A_{\mathfrak{p}}}(E_{\mathfrak{p}}).$$

At the level of sheaves you get with $U:=Spec(A)\subseteq X, \mathcal{E}(U):=\tilde{E}(U)$

$$Sym^d_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{E})_x \cong (Sym^d_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{E})_U)_x \cong   Sym^d_A(E)_{\mathfrak{p}} \cong $$

$$ Sym^d_{A_{\mathfrak{p}}}(E_{\mathfrak{p}})\cong   Sym^d_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}(\mathcal{E}_x)$$

where $x\in X$ is the point corresponding to $\mathfrak{p}$

A similar argument proves the case for the exterior product.

In general if $(X, \mathcal{O})$ is a locally ringed topological space and $E$ is a left $\mathcal{O}$-module, define for any open set $U \subseteq X$

$$F(E)(U):= \wedge^r_{\mathcal{O}(U)}E(U).$$

it follows $F(E)$ is a presheaf on $X$ with the same stalks as $\wedge^r E$.
Let $I:=\{U\subseteq X\}_{x\in U}$ be the open sets of $X$ containing $x$. You want an isomorphism

$$lim_{U \in I}\wedge^r_{\mathcal{O}(U)} E(U) \cong \wedge^r_{lim_{U\in I}\mathcal{O}(U)}(lim_{U \in I}E(U)):=\wedge^r_{\mathcal{O}_x}E_x.$$

if the two objects

$$lim_{U \in I}\wedge^r_{\mathcal{O}(U)} E(U)\text{ and }\wedge^r_{\mathcal{O}_x}E_x$$

are to be isomorphic, you could prove that the right one satisfies the universal property of the left one. A direct limit is uniquely determined up to isomorphism by a universal property. If the two groups are isomorphic, there should be "canonical maps" between them.

**Note:** You must prove that you can take the direct limit on the left hand side. You must prove the system $\{\wedge^r_{\mathcal{O}(U)} E(U)\}_{U\in I}$ is a direct system of abelian groups.

There are canonical maps

$$\rho_U: \mathcal{O}(U) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_x $$

defined by

$$\rho_U(s):=(s,U)$$

and

$$\eta_U: E(U) \rightarrow E_x$$

with

$$\eta_U(e):=(e,U)\in E_x.$$

It seems this gives for any $U$ a "canonical" map

$$\phi_U: \wedge^r_{\mathcal{O}(U)}E(U) \rightarrow \wedge^r_{\mathcal{O}_x}E_x$$

defined by

$$\phi_U(e_1\wedge \cdots \wedge e_r):=(e_1,U) \wedge\cdots \wedge (e_r,U) \in \wedge^r_{\mathcal{O}_x}E_x.$$

It could be this map "passes to the limit":

If this is the case you get a map

$$\phi_x:=lim_{U\in I}\phi_U: lim_{U\in I}\wedge^r_{\mathcal{O}(U)}E(U) \rightarrow \wedge^r_{\mathcal{O}_x}E_x.$$

and we may suspect that $\phi_x$ is an isomorphism.

**Hint:** Maybe there is a map in the other direction defined as follows: For any open set $U\in I$ there is a map

$$i_U: \wedge^r E(U) \rightarrow lim_{U\in I}\wedge^r E(U).$$

Given any element $z:=e_1\otimes \cdots \otimes e_r \in E_x^{\otimes r}$, choose representatives $e_i^* \in E(U)$ mapping to $e_i$. There is a map

$$\psi_U^*:E_x^{\otimes r} \rightarrow lim_{U \in I}\wedge^r E(U)$$

defined by

$$\psi_U^*(z):=i_U(e_1^*\wedge \cdots \wedge e_r^*) \in lim_{U\in I} \wedge^r E(U).$$

The map $\psi_U$ factors through the exterior product: You get a well defined map

$$ \psi_x: \wedge^r(E_x) \rightarrow lim_{U\in I}\wedge^rE(U).$$

If $\psi_x \circ \phi_x = \phi_x \circ \psi_x=Id$ the claim follows. You must check if the above constructions are well defined and give an isomorphism.

**Note:** When trying to prove two constructions in homological algebra are isomorphic you may in many cases construct two explixit maps - one in each direction. Here is a "list of explicit isomorphisms in homological algebra":

[The "magic diagram" is cartesian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778186/the-magic-diagram-is-cartesian/4062951#4062951)

[Prove $\phi$ to be isomorphism (an exercise in commutative algebra)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130474/prove-phi-to-be-isomorphism-an-exercise-in-commutative-algebra/4130498#4130498)

[Form of basic open set of affine scheme: The intersection of two basic open sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086763/form-of-basic-open-set-of-affine-scheme-the-intersection-of-two-basic-open-sets/4120679#4120679)

Comment: Thank your for your answer, but I'm not sure if this helps me in my situation. At the end of your answer, it seems to me that we make use of the fact that we can write $\mathcal{E}=\tilde{E}$, but as I'm not assuming that my $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$ is quasi-coherent, I'm not sure if we can do this.

Comment: I don't have a particular sheaf, but the context of the statement I would like to see is more general than just quasi-coherent sheaves.